# How to make PHP libraries loosely coupled?

Tags: php, oop, language-agnostic

I have some libraries in my 'framework' like routing, config, logger,... I want them to be independent of each other, like some of well known PHP frameworks make them.

I understand all the principles of loose coupling, but I have no clue how to follow both loose coupling and DRY principles. If I make routing library that  config and logger, then I don't repeat myself, but if I want to use router on its own it won't work. Similarly if I write logging and config code into my routing library, I would repeat myself.

Comment: Have you taken a look at design patterns? Like factories, singletons, observers, chain of command etc?

Comment: @yossarian: Singletons for loose coupling? Really?

Comment: Singletons are widely considered as anti-pattern in PHP world for several reasons. Avoid them if possible.

Comment: I agree, avoid singletons, but the other patterns might be useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Loose coupling* normally means that your components do not expect a concrete instance but just one instance that has a compatible interface.

Each collaborator can be replaced then with a different one of the same type. The code is not dependent on a concrete implementation of one of those any longer.

So:

- Do not use:

  - global (static) functions

    ```
    Foo:bar();
    ```
  - class based programming (passing a classname around)

    ```
    stream_wrapper_register("var", "VariableStream");
    ```
  - global constants

    ```
    if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )   
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
    ```
- But:

  - Use objects

    ```
    $foo->bar();
    ```
  - Program against interfaces

    ```
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
    ```
  - Unit-test with mocks

    ```
    $logger = $this->getMock('LoggerInterface', array('log'));
    ```

See as well:

- [Don't be STUPID: GRASP SOLID! (Dec 2011; by NikiC)](http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/27/Dont-be-STUPID-GRASP-SOLID.html)

Comment: Watch this talk: it has good, real-life examples on how to follow the SOLID principles in your code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4Fmzvsvt_o

Comment: Yes, it's based on the article by NikiC linked. Nice catch but the sound quality is awful which makes it hard to listen to.