# does decopuling result in losing cohesion?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Many times I experience that if I want to make a not-tight coupled system, it helps to be independent but also hurts the cohesion. Example:

model:

```
$record = Doctrine::getById(1);
// $record is now a bean: UserClass with getters
```

view:

```
<body>
<?php echo $record->getName().'; '.$record->getId(); ?>
</body>
```

this is bad since now this view is coupled to `UserClass`. I can refactor it to be independent:

model:

```
$record = Doctrine::getById(1);
$name = $record->getName();
$id = $record->getId();
```

view:

```
<body>
<?php echo $name.'; '.$id; ?>
</body>
```

now view is maximum independent - but also loses its cohesion. At the first solution, the data are in one place (`UserClass`) and cannot be scattered - unlike now. We can easily introduce a but which may cause that `$id` is a from another record while `$name` is from another?

Comment: You can use hydration in doctrine to convert your user class to a regular array/object. Which will let you do `$user->name` or `$user['name']`, keeping cohersion and not using your UserClass. That being said though, Doctrine entity classes are/can be/should be(?) decoupled from the Doctrine system to the extent that they're in fact normal classes. If they are I don't really see any problem of depending on them.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain what you call cohesion here you should try using patterns such as inheritance, dependency injection and factories. These will allow you to make a more loosely coupled system while maintaining a very high level of cohesion or readability.

I think you might want to read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16118188/6838730) and [this article](http://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code/)